# Bash script awkwardness with pwd

Tags: bash, cd, pwd

I've got a strange issue while working with a bash script. Here it is:

```
PWD=${pwd}
# several commands
cd /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/
# more commands
cd $PWD
# I expect that I returning to my directory, 
# but $PWD contains current dir - /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/
```

This behavior is kind of lazy. `$PWD` stores command, which calculates the current directory and returns it at the moment we call `$PWD`, but I want to store the string variable in it. How to do that?

Comment: With bash, `cd -` gets you back to the last directory you were at. Or use pushd/popd.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

PWD is an environmental variable and is changed when you change the directory.

Use a different name for the variable,

eg:

```
MYPWD=${PWD}  #or MYPWD=$(pwd)
cd /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/
cd $MYPWD
```

Comment: Just let it be here as a documentation question. About a half of an hour to solve this problem.

Comment: It's a good idea to use lowercase (or mixed-case) names for your variables, to avoid conflicts like this...

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
PWD=`pwd`
```

Or:

```
PWD=$(pwd)
```

Both expressions will execute the *pwd* command and store the command output in the shell variable PWD.  There is plenty of discussion on the web about when to use each style.  The one point that I recall is that the "$(cmd)" approach allows for nesting of commands, e.g.

```
CURRENT_BASENAME=$(basename $(pwd))
```

Edit - It just occurred to me that PWD is a built in shell variable that always expands to the  current working directory.

Comment: No. I was badly concentrated and didn't mention, that $PWD - is a system variable and ALWAYS points to current dir. `HPWD=$(pwd)` worked just fine.

Comment: When you edit, you should edit to correct the post, not use edit to make a comment at the end of your post.  You should fix this to avoid downvotes. It's confusing to people who may not read the entire answer.

Answer (score 0):

you may also find 
`cd -`
usefull